# How to cast void* to vector<char *>?

Tags: c++

There is a function which takes `void*`

After passing my `vector<char*>`, how do I cast it back to `vector<char*>` and print its content using casting in C++?

Example:

```
void testFunction(void* data){

   //cast data back to vector<char *> and print its content


}


int main()
{
   std::vector<char *> arg(1);
    std::string someString = "testString";
        arg[0] = (char *)someString.c_str();
        testFunction(&arg);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry its just arg. i edited

Comment: i tried some static_cast by checking already existing questions but no luck

Comment: This is [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please explain why you asking this question, since if we know root cause we can provide better solution/explanation. Who know maybe you can discard this terrifying `void*` (this is a code smell). If you are using some external function explain/describe that (especially what is yours and what is external).

Comment: Let's see - We have a vector holding a single pointer, which is a const cast pointer to the internals of a std::string. And then we pass this as a `void*` to some function?! If this isn't already a criminal offence, it ought to be!  :-) It surely would be a firing offence in any code review (except on April 1).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `static_cast` to cast a `void*` pointer to *almost* any other type of pointer. The following code works for me:

```cpp
void testFunction(void* data)
{
    std::vector<char*>* vecdata = static_cast<std::vector<char*>*>(data);
    for (auto c : *vecdata) std::cout << c;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `reinterpret_cast`

```
vector<char*>* parg = reinterpret_cast<vector<char*>*>(data);
char* mystr = parg->at(0);
```

Comment: You could also use a C-style cast - but why would you want to, when the much 'safer' `static_cast` works?

Comment: I think `static_cast` doesnt like that because its unsafe. The compiler cant check whether this is correct.

Comment: Compilers can do a *lot* more safety checking on `static_cast` than they can on `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Casting from `void*` should be done with a `static_cast`, not a `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<char*>& myVec= *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<char*>*>(data);
std::cout<<myVec[0];
```

Well actually this worked.